Retired, don't need webpage, want to keep email addresses
I’ve had a business for many years for which I’ve had a webpage and email being hosted by a standard provider. I’ve retired and don’t need the webpage anymore. Is there some way I can keep my email addresses only but at a reduced cost with another service?

At a technical level, mail hosting functions entirely independently of web hosting. Put simply, cancel your web hosting plan, keep your email hosting plan, and keep your yearly domain registration at your domain registrar. Instead of having three bills (web, email and domain), you should be able to get it down to two bills (email and domain).
